# How to get Jetty with SSL working

Tags: java, rest, ssl, jetty

Sorry for the poor title, I'm not really sure what's going on here.  I'm trying to get a jetty server which previously worked with http to now work over https.  I've followed a few articles and been playing around for the past few days with it, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

This is my code for setting up and starting the server:

```
    // Create jetty server
    this.server = new Server();

    HttpConfiguration http_config = new HttpConfiguration();
    http_config.setSecureScheme("https");
    http_config.setSecurePort(3972);

    // Configure Connector for http
    ServerConnector http = new ServerConnector(server, new HttpConnectionFactory(http_config));
    http.setPort(3971);
    http.setIdleTimeout(300000);

    // HTTPS Configuration
    HttpConfiguration https_config = new HttpConfiguration(http_config);
    https_config.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath("data/derkle.jks");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("XXXXXXXXXX");

    ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server, new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"), new HttpConnectionFactory(https_config));
    sslConnector.setPort(portSecureNo);

    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { http, sslConnector });

    this.server.setHandler(vaultServer);
    this.server.start();
    this.server.join();
```

This runs fine, and the thread joins successfully at server.join().  I get the following output:

```
2016-01-22 10:52:30.587:INFO::main: Logging initialized @269ms
2016-01-22 10:52:42.124:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.14.v20151106
2016-01-22 10:52:42.227:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@5674fb70{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:3971}
2016-01-22 10:52:43.044:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@d9f8120{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:3972}
2016-01-22 10:52:43.045:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @12729ms
```

All looks good, but when I try to send a request to it, I don't appear to get anything passed to my implementation of AbstractHandler.  Which has a handle function like this:

```
@Override
public void handle(
        String target,
        Request baseRequest,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    Validate.isTrue(this.endPointManager != null, "This has not been initialised.");

    target = target.replace('\\', '/');
    if (target.startsWith("/"))
        target = target.substring(1);

    if (target.endsWith("/"))
        target = target.substring(0, target.length() - 1);

    String[] targets = stelar.extx.StringUtil.stringSplit(target, '/');

    if ((targets.length == 1) && (targets[0].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(STATUS_URI))) {

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
        return;
    }
    else {

        // Display help is the help uri is passed, or not uri is passed
        if ((target.isEmpty()) || (targets[0].equalsIgnoreCase(IURLHandler.HELP_URI))) {

            displayHelp(this.rootHandler, baseRequest, response);
            return;
        }
    }

    parseURI(targets, 0, baseRequest, request, response, this.rootHandler);
}
```

I'm sending requests to the server from the 'Advanced REST client' which is a chrome extension.  I also tried with Curl, but I can't seem to get SSL working with it.

[image]

I've tried calling the following addresses:

```
https://localhost:3971/
https://localhost:3971
https://localhost:3972/
https://localhost:3972
```

EDIT:

So I decided to revert back to using http as a sanity check, and I noticed that it also had stopped working.  The only other thing that I've changed since is the version of jetty I was using.  Originally I used a library called jetty-all, but it didn't seem to contain support for SSL, so I switched to jetty-distribuition-9.2.14.v20151106, which is split into multiple jar files.  I'm wondering if I need to include some of these additional libraries (though I'm not getting any compile issues, so it doesn't seem like that would be the case).

Comment: Have you considered using Apache HTTPD as reverse proxy? IMHO the fastest way to add HTTPS and other features, without touching the application server at all. (Apache is only one option, you can also check out nginx and others)